# Calling existing excel file using OLE - delphi

Tags: delphi, ole

I have an excel file which contains a format for the data that will be passed in it. Can Someone help me how to open an existing excel file?

```
var
  myExcel:variant;
begin
  myExcel:=CreateOleObject('Excel.application');
  myExcel.caption:='Summary of Check Issued';
  myExcel.visible:=false;
  myexcel.workbooks.add(1);
end
```

that statement will create a new excel file but what i want is a statement to just open my existing excel file.

Comment: There is a general rule how to solve that kind of questions. Launch Excel - fgo to the menu (different in defferent Excel version, unless you installed Classic Menu) and turn on the **macro recorder** - the you do what you need, like opening files or changing cell format or anything. Then you go back to **macros** mnager dialog, stop the recorder and start Editing the new macro - that macro would be VBA program that does what you just done by mouse and keyboard. You then just translate the ready program from VBA to Delphi and here it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact line of code you are looking for is:

```
WorkBook := ExcelFile.WorkBooks.Open('yourfilename.xls');
```

The complete code might look something like this:

```
var
   ExcelFile : Variant;
   WorkBook : Variant;
   WorkSheet : Variant;

begin

  // Open Excel OLE
  ExcelFile :=  CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');

  // Handle WoorkBook
  if not VarIsNull(ExcelFile) then begin
      WorkBook := ExcelFile.WorkBooks.Open('yourfilename.xls');

      if not VarIsNull(WorkBook) then begin
      // Handle Sheet
          WorkSheet := WorkBook.WorkSheets.Item['yourSheetName'];
      end;

  end;
```

Refer to [this article](http://usingdelphi.blogspot.com/2012/09/manage-excel-from-delphi-i.html) for more detailed information.

Comment: hi . i got an error "Sorry, we couldn't find Account.xls". We're should i supposed to put the file? i already pasted it on the folder where my project is located

Comment: i also tried WorkBook := myExcel.WorkBooks.Open('D:\files\project\Account.xls') but it still has the same error

Comment: First make sure that your file has the extension `.xls`. If you made the file with a different version of Excel than the one I was using, then it may have a slightly different extension, perhaps `.xlsx`. If that doesn't work, try replacing `yourfilename.xls` with the full path to the file, that may look like `c:\users\tom\documents\account.xls`.

Comment: If all else fails, try renaming the file to begin with a lowercase `a` like `account.xls`.

Comment: No problem! What part exactly fixed it?

Comment: im too close actually . i already tried WorkBook := myExcel.WorkBooks.Open('D:\files\project\April.xlxs') . got mistaken with the x and s . but i realize it was .xlsx when i saw ur comment  . haha